# Primefaces ajax behaviour vs ICEfaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, icefaces

I'm new to JSF and ICEfaces is the first component library I used.
With ICEfaces, If I change an `inputText` value via backing bean using `commandButton` `action`, those changes just reflect to the UI.

But with Primefaces I have to mention explicitly what component should be updated using `update` attribute of the `commandButton`.

Is this the expected behavior ?
If so, is there a standard for JSF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With stock JSF and with most other frameworks that extend it, you need to specify the update region for Ajax requests.  ICEfaces figures out the differences and the changes that need to be applied on the server-side. So that you don't need specify the specific update regions if you don't want to.  However that option is still available to you as well if you need it.